# Is there any difference between these two Java codes Snaps?

Tags: java, global-variables, mutable

1.

```
public static StringBuffer setString2(StringBuffer s)
{
    s.append("::1st word");
    return s;
}

static StringBuffer sbGlobal = new StringBuffer("before");

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    System.out.println(setString2(sbGlobal));
}
```

2.

```
public static void setString(StringBuffer s)
{
    s.append("::1st word");
}

static StringBuffer sbGlobal = new StringBuffer("before");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    setString(sbGlobal);
    System.out.println(sbGlobal);
}
```

Can anyone explain to me, if there is any difference here? Also which method is better, if there is any difference, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is a mutable class. The `setString2()` method takes a `StringBuffer` as argument, modifies it, and also returns it. The `setString()` method takes a `StringBuffer` as argument, modifies it, but doesn't return it.

Both programs do the same thing and produce the same result. The second solution is cleaner though: there is no reason to return something that is passed as argument. Indeed, the caller already has a reference to the object that it passes as argument, and returning this object is thus useless, and causes confusion: why does the method return a StringBuffer? Is this StringBuffer the same as the one passed as argument, or a new one? Is the StringBuffer passed as argument modified, or is the method returning a modified copy of it?

The second method doesn't have all these ambiguities.

Side note: You shouldn't use `StringBuffer` anymore. Prefer `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Thanks @NandkumarTekale. You're almost there: only 192600 points missing :)

Comment: Toooooo optimistic :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static StringBuffer setString2(StringBuffer s)
    {
        s.append("::1st word");
        return s;
    }
```

That above method returning the `StringBuffer` object, which is modified by append method.  So while you are doing

```
System.out.println(setString2(sbGlobal));
```

That returned `StringBuffer` object which is appended by some `String` and that is printing.

Where as in Second case there is no return type and its `void`.

```
public static void setString(StringBuffer s)
    {
        s.append("::1st word");
    }
```

So the statement

```
 System.out.println(setString2(sbGlobal)); //compile error because of void
```

When you call

```
 setString(sbGlobal);
```

It modifying the `StringBuffer` object  and now you are printing the `sbGlobal` Object

```
System.out.println(sbGlobal);
```